# Need to optimize query efficiency - Query utilizes max(date)

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have an issue where my query is taking forever to pull data.  I need a strategy on how to speed up the process.  Table one is a particular list of customernumber's, this table contains 4257 customernumbers. Table 2 contains transaction activity on a daily basis and has probably over 1 million rows of data.

I need to pull transaction data from table 2 based on the max(saledate) found for customer numbers listed in table 1.

```
select max(saledate), Name, customernumber 
from Table2
where customernumber in (select * from Table1);
```

This query takes an eternity.  How can I speed this up?  I don't mind processing this in batches.

```
   Table1                                    Table2
CustomerNumber      CustomerNumber   Name  SaleDate    TransactionAmount
     1           |        5           Bill   3/1/2014          $20
     2           |        5           Bill   3/21/2015         $30 
     3           |        1           John   3/1/2016          $0
     4           |        9           Jane   1/1/2014          $10
     5           |        11          Josh   3/1/2016          $5
     7           |        5           Bill   6/8/2015          $60
     6           |        7           Nair   7/21/2014         $17
     2           | 
     8           | 
     9           |
     10          |
     11          |
     12          |
     13          |
     14          |
```

ANSWER:

```
select * from table1 a
inner join
(
select max(saledate), name, customernumber, transactionamount
from table2 where transactionamount <> 0 group by customernumber) b 
on a.customernumber = b.customernumber;
```

Thank you Wei.  This dramatically improved the speed of the query.  I knew my query was going about it in a non-efficient manner.

Comment: Why don't  you join the tables based on `CustomerNumber`? This should speed up your query. The inner query you have now is done for each `CustomerNumber`

Comment: Include the full Create table statements for table 1 and table 2 so we can see how the tables are structured. `show create table [your table]`

Comment: Indexing the columns of your where condition will speed up your query like anything.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thank you for your assistance.  This sped up the query dramatically.

Comment: I think skipping the group by clause also might be the reason for slow performance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In SO, questions are not the right place to put answers - even incorrect answers!!